# I have output like this array ( 'myField' => 'given value in text area', 'myCheckboxes' => array ( 0 => 'someValue1', 1 => 'someValue2', ), )

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

am getting all these values from a form submission .

i want to split these repeated values into separate variable and i want to store them into mysql DB.

**this the output**

```
array ( 'myField' => 'given value in text area', 
        'myCheckboxes' => array ( 0 => 'someValue1', 
                                  1 => 'someValue2', ), 
        )
```

i want to store each value into DB like this

myField = given value in text area

```
myCheckboxes1 = someValue1

myCheckboxes2 = someValue2
```

**i tried code like this**

```
<?php 
    $field  = $_POST['myField'];
    $checkValue1 = $_POST['myCheckboxes.(0)'];
    $checkValue2 = $_POST['myCheckboxes.(1)'];

    echo "$field"; //getting this output correctly
    echo "$checkValue1"; //empty output
    echo "$checkValue2"; //empty output
?>
```

Comment: Try using `$_POST['myCheckboxes'][0]` and `$_POST['myCheckboxes'][1]`

Comment: tried but not printing any output

Comment: Use `var_dump($_POST)` to see the full contents of the `$_POST` array, maybe the chekboxes are not grouped as an array (you have a problem when you defined its name) or are empty (you have a problem with the associated inputs or maybe in the `onsubmit()` event).

Comment: Thanks Alberto,

Now working perfect.

i make them separate with this code:
     
`echo $_POST['myField']; echo $_POST['myCheckboxes2']; echo $_POST['myCheckboxes1'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(I'm reposting my comment as an answer since it seems that it solved the problem)*

To see why you get empty values use `var_dump($_POST)` to see the full contents of the `$_POST` array (that is an useful debug technique for PHP).

You can get several outcomes:

- Maybe the checkboxes are not grouped as an array, then you have a problem when you defined its name in the HTML.
- Maybe there are grouped but with empty values, then you have a problem with the associated inputs or in the `onsubmit()` event.